# Filter input of type file based on name or id

Tags: javascript, input, selector

I i need a method that gives you back an `input` of type `file` based on its `id` or `name` (whatever works of these two)

What i tried so far:

```
<input type="file" name="a"/>  //if id is better , then id..
<input type="file "name="b"/>
<input type="text" "name"="c"/>

<input onchange="window.getInput(this.value)" type="text"/>

window.getInput=function(value){
   var file=f(value);
}

f=function (fileName) {
        var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file ,name=$'fileName']').files[0];
        console.log("File name is :" + fileName);
        return file;

    }
```

Comment: This example will not work. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? You should be able to look up how to select by ID or name (A quick search of this site will give you hundreds of examples) and then you just need to use the logic `if(selected a thing){return thing}` for each selector.

Comment: It does not select based on the `fileName`.I have checked on how to use multiple selectors on `jQuery` documentation , but i did not find how to  compose conditions of type `[  ]`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are those text inputs or radio buttons?

Comment: I  have updated my question and added further clarifications .

Comment: Take a look of my edited answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your example working, to select an input by 2 attributes must be separated by []

```js
 var getInput = function(value){
  if(value !== undefined && value !== ""){
  
     var file = f(value);
     console.log("File name is :", file);
  }
}

var f = function(fileName) {
  var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file ][name=' + fileName + ']').files[0];
  return file;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="a" />
<input type="file" name="b" />
<input oninput="getInput(this.value)" type="text"/>
```